# Qt linux installation paths

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I have Qt 5.7 installed on Debian and I am trying to build a legacy application which uses QtWebKit.

I have downloaded the updated QtWebKit libs from [here](https://github.com/annulen/webkit/releases/tag/qtwebkit-tp5).

The tarball contains files to be put in the directories named `include`, `lib` and `mkspecs`. On Windows these directories are very easily found in the installation path. But I am unable to find the paths for these on Linux. Any help will be appreciated.

**Note**: For those who are uninformed, Qt replaced `QtWebKit`(based on Webkit) with `QtWebEngine`(based on Chromium) in Qt version 5.6. Thus if you are using the official release of Qt 5.6 or above, you cannot build applications using QtWebkit. This is where the open source community stepped in and continued development of the `QtWebKit` libraries. You can more about it [here](http://qtwebkit.blogspot.in/2016/08/qtwebkit-im-back.html). To conclude, I have tried this on Windows and the modified version of `QtWebKit` offers huge benefits over the official one with a significant boost in performance and lot of bugs fixed.

Comment: It is not correct what you indicate in your note, you can compile QtWebkit with later versions of Qt 5.6, I have it compiled with Qt 5.10, download the source code: `qmake`,`make`, `sudo make install`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @eyllanesc. I was just wondering if there was a way other than building Qt from source myself.

Comment: What other kind of form do you expect?

Comment: On Windows, I have the official Qt 5.9 installed. Thus no `QtWebKit` by default. I downloaded the zip containing the headers and libs from the link I shared above. Extracted the contents and copied them into the respective directories in Qt installation path. Basically I copied files into the `include`, `lib`, `mkspecs` etc directories in `C:/Qt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/msvc2015/`. Now I can build applications using `QtWebKit` and it can dynamically link to the new libs I added. That simple! I did not have to build Qt from source on Windows. Was expecting the similar thing on Linux. Hope that's clear.

Comment: The style of windows is to create a DLL or lib for executable, in linux instead it entails only having the .a and .so for OS, and having many distros where there is no uniformity between versions, the most common in these cases is to compile it, in windows the compilation from the source code is very complicated, in linux it is very simple.

Comment: Aha! That's a good explanation. I will try compiling the Qt source on Linux then. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to download the latest Qt package for Linux from the Qt website.
You will have the latest QtWebKit package already ready to use.